# How do I substitute a variable inside this string in powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I'm still learning powershell & have a question...

If I have this string: (note single & double quotes)

```
'{"path":"https://somehttppage.com/Scripts/myscript.ps1"}'; "commandLine"=".\myscript.ps1"}
```

How can I put a variable in the line?
I've tried

```
$scr = "myscript.ps1"
'{"path":"https://somehttppage.com/Scripts/$scr"}'; "commandLine"=".\$scr"}
```

I've also tried

```
$scr = "myscript.ps1"
'{"path":"https://somehttppage.com/Scripts/$($scr)"}'; "commandLine"=".\$($scr)"}
```

But neither of these work & just give me errors....
(The top line works - but I'd like to substitute it & also learn something at the same time!)

I think the quotes are throwing me off...

Many thanks for any help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the template string contains no other expandable expressions, use `ExpandString()`:

```
$scr = 'myscript.ps1'
$template = @'
'{"path":"https://somehttppage.com/Scripts/myscript.ps1"}'; "commandLine"=".\$scr"}
'@

$string = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
```

If the template string is part of the source code, use a double-quoted here-string instead:

```
$scr = 'myscript.ps1'
$string = @"
'{"path":"https://somehttppage.com/Scripts/myscript.ps1"}'; "commandLine"=".\$scr"}
"@
```

Answer (score 0):

If you needed to NOT use a here string for some reason the above answer would change to:

```
$scr = 'myscript.ps1'
$string = "'{`"path`":`"https://somehttppage.com/Scripts/$scr`"}'; `"commandLine`"=`".\$scr`"}"
```